# Jwplayer can't play video in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, video, jwplayer

This is my first time using Jwplayer. I am trying to play a video using Jwplayer. The code I have written works in Firefox, IE, Opera but not in Chrome.

It is saying "error loading media : file cannot be played". My code is given below. I am also using CodeIgniter and Bootstrap.

```
<section class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="ad-video">Loading the player...</div>
                </div>
            </section>

$(document).ready(function(){
    jwplayer("ad-video").setup({
        file: "http://vatiali.com/assets/videos/choc.mp4",
        image: "http://vatiali.com/assets/images/black.jpg"
    });
});
```

Comment: fixed my problem. just add " primary: "flash" ".

Comment: I would look into the server MIME TYPE thought for MP4 files. That might be the root of the issue.

Comment: @LucasSerafim Why are you trying to edit the question to add a solution? If you solved this problem, then post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @eddard.stark Please see my answer. I suspect that you may still have an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that is the correct fix. I think that is a workaround which is masking the true problem.

The default setting for primary playback mode is HTML5. When operating with the default setting JWPlayer should automatically fallback to playing the video with flash if the browser does not support HTML playback for the video file and the Flash plugin is installed.

I suspect that your JWPlayer implementation only works with Flash.

Please test your implementation on a browser that does not have Flash installed but supports HTML5 playback of the video type you are using. I suspect it will not work.

---

To further troubleshoot this please revert the primary setting to the default, open the JavaScript console, refresh the page and tell us what error you see.

Here's a guess as to what the problem might be. Is the jwplayer.html5.js file located in the same directory as the jwplayer.js file? If not you can use the 'html5player' option t specify the location of the file.

Comment: thank you for your concern. jwplayer.html5.js file is in the same location. but when i try to play the file in chrome, it doesn't switch back to flash. it just shows "error loading media : file cannot be played". i looked in stackoverflow. somewhere it said to disable hardware accelaration. i did that and still nothing. don't know what to do else other then that.

Comment: Is there a web page you can send me the link to? If so I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the option for primary to 'flash' for my jwplayer setup. The code looks like

```
video_player_jw.setup({
        file: $('#source_url').val(),
        height: 360,
        width: 640,
        primary: 'flash'
    });
```

I am only doing this in chrome as it works fine with primary as html5 in all other browsers.